# .xib not loading properly on iOS 4.3, fine on 5.0?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, ios4, uiviewcontroller

I'm running into a tricky glitch.

I've got a .xib, which was created by XCode when I created a new `UIViewController` subclass.  It has quite a few elements, including some `UIButton`s, a bunch of `UILabel`s, a small `UIView` with some other views inside it, and a `UIImageView` containing a mostly-transparent image.

In `viewDidLoad`, I set the background color of the `UIImageView` to a color using a pattern image.

When I display this view controller in the simulator or on my iPhone 4 (both running iOS 5.1), everything goes smoothly; the patterned background displays, all the interactions work, and so on.

When I test on iOS 4.3, however (either in the simulator or on my iPod Touch 2G), it appears that everything I'm trying to manipulate based on an outlet (e.g. `[self.myBackgroundImageView setBackgroundColor...]` or `[self.mySegmentedControl setEnabled:NO]`)  just doesn't work at all.

The only even vaguely unusual thing I'm doing when the view gets presented is this, which makes it size properly in a popover:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {        
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(320, 480); // size of view in popover
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = size;

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

I really can't think of anything else that might be the problem.  I've cleaned, rebuilt, all that stuff.  Still no dice.

Has anyone else encountered this?

**UPDATE** per request by ott:

Added the following at the end of -viewDidLoad:

```
NSLog(@"self.myBackgroundImageView = %@ | %@", [self.myBackgroundImageView description], [[self.myBackgroundImageView backgroundColor] description]);
```

...The output is:

**`self.myBackgroundImageView = <UIImageView: 0x6d48c80; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6d48b60>> | <UIImageView: 0x5f459b0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x5f45890>> // kCGColorSpaceModelPattern 1`**

So... not nil.  Not sure what the story is here.

**UPDATE 2:**
It appears the disabling of a UISegmentedControl in iOS 4.3 doesn't dim its display, so that's what that part was about.  As for the background pattern image: I can't find confirmation of this, but I'm starting to think it's a bug in iOS 4 that makes a background color using a pattern-image UIColor not display properly on a UIImageView.  It works fine if I make the UIImageView have a clear background and put the pattern image UIColor as the background of the main view instead.  If anyone comes up with a workaround, or confirmation that this is indeed an iOS 4 bug, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: A popover on iPhone or iPod? I thought that's for iPad only?

Comment: It's a universal app; that code's irrelevant on the iPod touch, but still gets executed.

Comment: Can you put in some NSLog like `NSLog(@"self.myBackgroundImageView = %@", [self.myBackgroundImageView description]);` to see if the values are not nil?

Comment: Now again, NSLog() of the backgroundcolor only before and after you change it. Does it show a difference?

Comment: Yes.
"background color before = UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.333333 0.333333 0.333333 1"
"background color after = kCGColorSpaceModelPattern 1"

Comment: I wonder if it's indeed a problem with iOS4 then.